# C#/.Net launched process with exit code -2146234327

Tags: c#, process, exit-code

I have a C# 4 application which launches another one to execute some Python code. The Python code can be executed with no problems (checked on PythonWin).
In my app I see that the exit code is -2146234327. I've been Googling and couldn't figure out what does it mean.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-2146234327 is HRESULT code, typically looked for in hex. See [Interpreting HRESULTS returned from .NET/CLR: 0x8013XXXX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yizhang/archive/2010/12/17/interpreting-hresults-returned-from-net-clr-0x8013xxxx.aspx):

> `HOST_E_EXITPROCESS_TIMEOUT` `0x80131029` Process exited due to
>   Timeout escalation.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you can expand a bit about what it means? The process executes the given Python code successfully, but for some reason returns this exit code.

Comment: As you see MSDN does not explain the code, because it is bascially deeper internals. My best guess is that the code executed but the hosting process stayed alive for some time (unexpectedly?) and later on a cleanup pass forcefully closed it - and the code indicates the action. It does not say that the problem is with Puthon code itself.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve written a workaround based on the fact that this is a warning rather than an error.

I have included the following in the DOS Batch file that runs Analyse and Index Rebuild processes for ArcGIS

```
set myRC=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %myRC%
set Constant=-2146234327
echo %Constant%
if %myRC% EQU %Constant% set ERRORLEVEL=0
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

- Line 1 sets a variable to the value returned from the call command e.g. call D:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe D:\Analyze\Analyze.py >> D:\Analyze\Log\output.txt
- Line 2 echoes the value returned
- Line 3 sets a constant variable
- Line 4 echoes this out
- Line 5 compares the value returned from the CALL command against the constant and sets the ERRORLEVEL variable to zero if they match
- Line 6 echoes out the return Code.

Found this information elsewhere that may shed a little more light on the issue:

https://github.com/ucd-cws/arcpy_metadata/issues/13